# Use HTML Form Data in PHP Function - Wordpress Admin Page

Tags: php, forms

I have created a form on a tab in the user-edit page (which is extended through BuddyPress) to allow admins to add points manually using a function from the MyCred plugin. I'm fairly new to programming but am loving learning! Here is a snippet of my code. I have the form showing correctly, but when I submit I get directed to a page with "The link you followed has expired." I'm guessing this has to do with the "action" in my form?

In addition to the error I am also wondering if my function is written correctly. For instance, I don't think I have it setup where when the form is submitted it actually calls the function.

Any help would be appreciated!
Update: This is the only place the `addpoints` function is used. I created it to combine the data from the form with the `mycred_add` function. Just not sure how to call it when the form is submitted.
Also, to answer the question about why I used the `<form method="post" action="/admin-post.php">` for my form. No reason other than just what I gleaned from my searches online.

```
function addpoints($user_id, $reference, $data, $amount )
            {
            if (isset($_POST['award-type']) && isset($_POST['date']) && isset($_POST['notes']))
            {
              $reference = $_POST['award-type'];
              $data = $_POST['notes'];
              $amount = $_POST['award-type'];
              $user_id = isset( $_GET['user_id'] ) ? $_GET['user_id'] : 0;
              if ($amount = 'CIO Spotlight') {
                $amount = 30;
              }
              else if ($amount = 'TNCR Deep Dive'){
                $amount = 50;
              }
              else if ($amount = 'TNCR Quote'){
                $amount = 20;
              }
              else if ($amount = 'TNCR Interview'){
                $amount = 30;
              }
              else if ($amount = 'TNCR Contributing Article'){
                $amount = 50;
              }
              else if ($amount = 'CION Endorsement'){
                $amount = 50;
              }
            mycred_add($reference, $user_id, $amount, $data);
            }

            }
  ?>
  <div class="bp-profile-field">
    <p style="font-size:17px; font-weight:600;">Add Points For User<hr></p>
    <div style="margin-left:15px">
         <form method="post" action="/admin-post.php">
<!--Select Point Type-->
         <label for="Award">Award Type:</label>
            <br>
          <input list="award-type" id="award" name="award-type">
            <datalist id="award-type">
                <option value="CIO Spotlight">
            <option value="TNCR Deep Dive">
                <option value="TNCR Quote">
            <option value="TNCR Interview">
            <option value="TNCR Contributing Article">
                <option value="Host A Learning Series">
            <option value="CION Endorsement">
            </datalist>
            <br>
            <br>
<!-- Input Date-->
         <label for="date">Date:</label>
            <br>
            <input type="date" id="award_date" name="date"
             value="">
            <br>
            <br>
<!--Input Notes-->
         <label for="notes">Notes:</label><br>
            <textarea id="notes" name="notes" rows="5" cols="33"> Enter extra details here. </textarea>
         <br/><br/>
<!--Submit Button-->
         <input type="submit" value="Award Points"><br/><br/>
        </form>
     </div>
  </div>
    <?php

  }
```

Comment: can you add some information about how and where `addpoints` is used? Was there a reason you used `<form method="post" action="/admin-post.php">` for your form tags action? Note that you can't ask about the MyCred plugin here, 3rd party plugin dev support questions are offtopic here and not in this stacks scope. Buddypress is on topic though as it's an official project, but if you can't get the points to add even if the form submits that's not something you can get help for here. Use the `edit` link to update your question

Comment: @TomJNowell Thanks for the info about MyCred being off topic, totally fine with that! I have used their function and gotten it to work correctly in other instances so I'm not too worried.  The `addpoints` function was something I created to combine the form data with the mycred function. It is not used or called anywhere else. Really just trying to figure out the process of creating a form and calling that data in a separate function.

Comment: Sounds like you may need to read up on [WP Nonces](https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Nonces) if you're using an endpoint already set up by MyCred - look how they process the data on that endpoint

Comment: @TracyKistler it's unclear how and where the function is being called, and that matters greatly, if only so the question is easier to understand, please add it, as well as where in your codebase this is located, e.g. is this in a theme/plugin? Are you calling it on a hook? In a page template?

Comment: @TomJNowell Sorry if I wasn't clear :) I have not called it anywhere as I'm unsure of where and how to call it. I'm a newb, just fumbling through this.

Comment: hmm if you aren't calling then I'm not sure how you got the "The link you followed has expired." message, can you update your code to include what you tried that lead to that error? Your Q says you have the form showing, but you didn't provide any information about _how_. Even if the code has issue it's important to include as much context as you can, even if it's code that you know doesn't work, how you tested it is just as important as the function

Comment: I think you might be looking for something like [`admin_post_action`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/admin_post_action/).